# Convert java map to native object rhino

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I try to convert *Java* `map<String, Object>` with hierarchical structure to native object via recursive transformation each value of map to native object and make

`nobj.defineProperty(entry.getKey(), value, READONLY);`

When I use this native object in *js*, I see that object is `[object Object]`
and its inner fields are `[object Object]`.

But when I use *js* methods like `hasOwnProperies` it throws exception:

> org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find default value
>   for object.

How can I use basic *js* functions with native object?